# What UTM stands for in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

There are several `utm_` parameters in Google Analytics. I am just wondering what `utm` shortcut stands for and where it comes from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is short for [Urching Tracking Module(](https://support.google.com/urchin/answer/28307?hl=en)/Monitor). Urchin was a company whose logfile analyzer formed the basis for the original Google Analytics after the company was aquired by Google in 2005.

The standalone Urchin product was discontinued in 2012 after Google had developed the measurement protocol (the data collected via MP is no longer compatible with Urchin).

However Google kept the parameter names, I assume so that people do not have to change their implementations for campaign tracking (after all this is more or less a cosmetic issue).